# Getting "Cannot call 'hline' with argument 'price'='level'. An argument of 'series int' type was used but a 'input float' is expected."

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
var o = 21304
hline(o, "OPEN PRICE", color.green, hline.style_solid, 1, true)

var rg = 100

for  i = -rg to rg
    var level = o + i
    if (level % 100 == 0)
        hline(level, "p", color.green, hline.style_solid, 2)
```

I want to draw a horizontal line on the chart on certain levels based on the value of that level, but i am getting the above mentioned error in the code above

Exactly like the green line drawn in the chart using the hline function of pine script:

[image: Exactly like the green line drawn in the chart using the hline function of pine script]

Comment: you cant use `hline` for this case. Use lines https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Lines_and_boxes.html#lines

Answer (score 0):

The `hline()` function cannot be called in the local scope of an `if`/`for` block, use `line.new()` instead:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)
var o = 21304
hline(o, "OPEN PRICE", color.lime, hline.style_solid, 1, true)

var rg = 100
for  i = -rg to rg
    level = o + i
    if (level % 100 == 0)
        line.new(bar_index, level, bar_index +1, level, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, color.red, line.style_solid, 2)
```

[image]